# 3In bash, is there a way with (preferably vi set) to join previous commands together?

Tags: bash, command-line

I know I can

```
command1 && command2; command3
```

Is there a way that if I do 3 commands at the command line to join them together other then copying and pasting?

So:

```
command1
command2
command3
```

Magic keystrokes to get...

```
command1 && command2; command3
```

Comment: Note that `&&` is not just a simple join - if you wanted that then use `;`.  The `&&` runs commands from left to right until one is unsuccessful (has a non-zero return code).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware.  I'll edit and put a ; in place as the question is more about joining previous commands together.

Answer (score 1):

In vi mode, you can hit `v` in normal mode to open your `$EDITOR` (in emacs mode, C-x C-e).

If you paste

```
command1
command2
command3
```

then save and exit, the commands will run in order as if in a script.

You can also join them with `&&` using your editor macros, if you want the commands to abort if one fails.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way with the editor keys, but you can do it with [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html#Event-Designators):

```
~$ echo foo
foo
~$ echo bar
bar
~$ echo baz
baz
~$ !-3 && !-2 && !-1      # !-3 = three commands ago
echo foo && echo bar && echo baz
foo
bar
baz
~$
```

The invocation `!-3 && !-2 && !-1` pulls three commands from your history and drops them in, separated by the `&&`s.  You can also pull by text, with `!foo` for a command starting with `foo`, or `!?foo?` for a command containing `foo`.

**Edit** Per your question edit,

```
!-3 && !-2 ; !-1
```

will do just as well.  Don't forget the spaces around the `&&` and `;`, just to keep your sanity :) .